# Разбиение данных с помощью resample

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

У меня есть набор двухдневных данных, то есть 1.03.2019, 3.03.2019 и т.д. Моя задача - `downsample` этих данных до дневных с помощью `pandas`. Я решил сделать это с помощью `resample('D')`.

Пример входных данных:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+-------+
|    Date    | OutletName | ProductName | Sales |
+------------+------------+-------------+-------+
| 2019-01-01 | A          | butter      | 3.2   |
| 2019-01-03 | A          | butter      | 5     |
| 2019-01-01 | B          | bread       | 12    |
| 2019-01-01 | A          | bread       | 2     |
| 2019-01-03 | B          | butter      | 3.4   |
| 2019-01-05 | A          | butter      | 4     |
| 2019-01-05 | A          | bread       | 3.9   |
| 2019-01-05 | B          | butter      | 0.5   |
| 2019-01-05 | B          | bread       | 1.7   |
| ...        |            |             |       |
+------------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

Немного про сами данные. Это таблица, в которой данные могут быть разбиты на уникальные ячейки по столбцам `OutletName` и `ProductName`. То есть, когда мы выделяем отдельный `DataFrame` с помощью `df[(df['OutletName'] == 'A') & (df['ProductName'] == 'butter')]`, то получаем набор данных с неповторяющейся, уникальной в этом `DataFrame` датой. Из-за этого я решил вначале разбить данные по отдельным ячейкам, применить в них `.resample('D').pad(1)` для дублирования информации, а затем разделить столбец `Sales` пополам (чтобы общий объём продаж сохранился). Мой код:

```py
cells = []
i = 0
for outlet in df['OutletName'].unique():
    for product in df[df['OutletName'] == outlet]['ProductName'].unique():
        temp = df[(df['OutletName'] == outlet) & 
                  (df['ProductName'] == product)].resample('D').pad(1)

        temp['Sales'] /= 2
        i += 1

        cells.append(temp)
```

И затем собираем все в один `DataFrame`:

```py
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
for cell in cells:
    df_final = pd.concat([df_final, cell], axis=0, sort=False)
```

UPDATE v2: точный пример того, что я хочу получить на выходе по этой таблице:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+-------+
|    Date    | OutletName | ProductName | Sales |
+------------+------------+-------------+-------+
| 2019-01-01 | A          | butter      | 1.6   |
| 2019-01-02 | A          | butter      | 1.6   |
| 2019-01-03 | A          | butter      | 2.5   |
| 2019-01-04 | A          | butter      | 2.5   |
| 2019-01-05 | A          | butter      | 2     |
| 2019-01-06 | A          | butter      | 2     |
| 2019-01-01 | A          | bread       | 1     |
| 2019-01-02 | A          | bread       | 1     |
| 2019-01-05 | A          | bread       | 1.95  |
| 2019-01-06 | A          | bread       | 1.95  |
| 2019-01-03 | B          | butter      | 1.7   |
| 2019-01-04 | B          | butter      | 1.7   |
| 2019-01-05 | B          | butter      | 0.25  |
| 2019-01-06 | B          | butter      | 0.25  |
| 2019-01-01 | B          | bread       | 6     |
| 2019-01-02 | B          | bread       | 6     |
| 2019-01-05 | B          | bread       | 0.85  |
| 2019-01-06 | B          | bread       | 0.85  |
| ...        |            |             |       |
+------------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

Проблема состоит в том, что идёт уже 4 день, а программа так и не завершилась...

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе пример того что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: @MaxU, добавил.

Comment: То что вы хотите получить не является `resample'ом` в строгом смысле. Например для `OutletName: A, ProductName: bread` в случае `resample` должны были также присутствовать даты: `[2019-01-03, 2019-01-04]`

Comment: @MaxU, Эти даты будут после resample заполнены NaN, и я уберу эти строки, насколько я понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
In [23]: res = (pd.concat([df, df.assign(Date=df["Date"]+pd.offsets.Day(1))],
    ...:                  ignore_index=True)
    ...:          .sort_values(["OutletName", "ProductName", "Date"])
    ...:          .eval("Sales = Sales / 2")
    ...:          .reset_index(drop=True))
    ...:

In [24]: res
Out[24]:
         Date OutletName ProductName  Sales
0  2019-01-01          A       bread   1.00
1  2019-01-02          A       bread   1.00
2  2019-01-05          A       bread   1.95
3  2019-01-06          A       bread   1.95
4  2019-01-01          A      butter   1.60
5  2019-01-02          A      butter   1.60
6  2019-01-03          A      butter   2.50
7  2019-01-04          A      butter   2.50
8  2019-01-05          A      butter   2.00
9  2019-01-06          A      butter   2.00
10 2019-01-01          B       bread   6.00
11 2019-01-02          B       bread   6.00
12 2019-01-05          B       bread   0.85
13 2019-01-06          B       bread   0.85
14 2019-01-03          B      butter   1.70
15 2019-01-04          B      butter   1.70
16 2019-01-05          B      butter   0.25
17 2019-01-06          B      butter   0.25
```

Comment: Можете пояснить, почему `concat` и `assign` работают так, как у вас? Я не понимаю

Comment: А, мы взяли изначальный датафрейм, создали датафрейм с временными сдвигом на 1 день, но с такими же данными, а затем слили их вместе. Офигенно!

Comment: @Ratatuy129, вы все точно описали)

Answer (score 1):

Осталось переставить колонки и ресетнуть индекс, если надо

```
df.groupby(['OutletName', 'ProductName', 'Date']) \ 
  .agg(Sales=('Sales',lambda x: x /2), Date= ('Date',lambda x: [x.iloc[0],x.iloc[0]+ pd.DateOffset(1)])) \
  .explode('Date').reset_index(level='Date', drop=True)

                        Sales       Date
OutletName ProductName                  
A          bread         1.00 2019-01-01
           bread         1.00 2019-01-02
           bread         1.95 2019-01-05
           bread         1.95 2019-01-06
           butter        1.60 2019-01-01
           butter        1.60 2019-01-02
           butter        2.50 2019-01-03
           butter        2.50 2019-01-04
           butter        2.00 2019-01-05
           butter        2.00 2019-01-06
B          bread         6.00 2019-01-01
           bread         6.00 2019-01-02
           bread         0.85 2019-01-05
           bread         0.85 2019-01-06
           butter        1.70 2019-01-03
           butter        1.70 2019-01-04
           butter        0.25 2019-01-05
           butter        0.25 2019-01-06
```

Comment: Даже не начав разбираясь в вашем ответе, могу сразу сказать, что он мне не подойдёт. Я сейчас остановил работу, и в моём массиве `cells` 127408 таблиц, уже `resampled`. Ваше решение классное, но в моём случае оно будет работать века